# Firebase Client SDK causing 404 and Offline Issues in SvelteKit Web App on Vercel

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, serverless, vercel, sveltekit

I am encountering an issue with my SvelteKit web app deployed on Vercel, where the frontend shows a 404 error, and the Vercel logs indicate that Firebase cannot retrieve the document as it is offline. This issue seems to occur when a user opens the website and keeps it open for an extended period.

It appears that the Firebase client SDK might be going offline for one server instance on Vercel, affecting all other users. I have around 10-12 people using the website concurrently.

Has anyone else experienced a similar problem, and if so, how did you address it? Are there any best practices or configurations I should be aware of to prevent the Firebase client from going offline, especially in a multi-user environment where client SDK functions are called on the server side?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.